# Ropsten Network - geth console does'nt give updated blocknumber

Tags: testrpc, testnets, ropsten, geth-debugging

I have used the command :

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303,enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303" --verbosity=6
```

to setup ropsten network in `localhost:8545` and attached geth.ipc using:

```
geth attach /datadir/geth.ipc
```

I can see that ropsten network in my localhost is syncing properly. When attached geth.ipc block number is not updated, its always showing`at block :  0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST)` even though the command `eth.syncing` gives incremented block number and after a while `current block` doesn't increment. `eth.blockNumber` is zero.

Network time synchronization is active.

Comment: Block number will get updated after sync is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed isto wait...allowing it to sync up for 1 day and night solved the issue. Ether I received via faucet is visible...`eth.blockNumber` gives 2894417.