# Create account via infura - ropsten network

Tags: web3js, testnets, ropsten, infura

I connected node with infura via web3js:

```
 var currentProviderr = new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/...");
```

How to create accounts in infura? How to view them?

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      infurawallet = accounts[0];
     }
```

infurawallet is showing undefined...

Comment: Hi , can you please tell your web3 version. Because i can't connect to ropsten like above.

Comment: web3 ^0.18.4 was the one I used...But then I connected to ropsten using [geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42903/ropsten-network-geth-console-doesnt-give-updated-blocknumber) instead of infura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot generate wallet with infura, because they can't hold the private key for you.

You also need to sign transaction before sending them.

[You might find Infura's documentation useful.](http://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/infura.html)