# Create account on Ethereum using Nethereum C#

Tags: ethereum-classic, nethereum, c#

I have studied the documents for creating a new account using Nethereum..

```
var ecKey = Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var privateKey = ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes().ToHex();
var account = new Nethereum.Web3.Accounts.Account(privateKey);
```

I want to create the account on Geth to start with for testing and then will migrate this to Ethereum live.  For this I am initalising Web3 with a constructor:

```
public Web3 _web3;

        public BaseEthererumService()
        {
            _web3 = new Web3(Config.EndPointURL);  // Prod "https://mainnet.infura.io";
            // Geth "localhost:8545";
        }
```

What I want is to write a new address to Geth (or Ethereum in prod) and to receive a new contract address back..

I have also tried:

```
public async Task<string> CreateAccount()
        {

            var account = await _web3.Personal.NewAccount.SendRequestAsync("123");

            return account;
        }
```

But this bombs out without returning any form of address. And when I run at a CLI geth account list I don't get anything back...

I simply need to register a new account on the blockchain programmatically using Nethereum.Web3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your own node? Infura doesn't support creation of accounts. If you are running your own node how do you launch geth? In the default configuration geth will not enable `personal` API for security reasons, you have to enable it explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

if you're running [Geth](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum), you'll need to point to the `geth.ipc` file instead of the endpoint url pointing to Infura.io for key generation because they won't store [your private key for you](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43510/create-account-via-infura-ropsten-network).

Basically, run Geth locally and add the `geth.ipc` file path to `Config.EndPointURL`, and you should be able to generate a key with it.